# OOP PHP method doesn't work when invoked within another method

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a PHP class for a Wordpress site. The following method works fine, but when I try to abstract it a bit by passing an argument and calling it within another method (see code further down below), it doesn't work anymore.

```
public function user_has_submitted_in_dog_category() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'submissions',
        'author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'submissions_categories',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'dog'
            )
        )
    );

    $user_posts = get_posts( $args );

    if( count( $user_posts ) )
        return true;

}
```

This is not working:

```
public function user_has_submitted_in_dog_category() {

    $this->user_has_submitted_in_animal_category( 'dog' );

}

public function user_has_submitted_in_animal_category( $category ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'submissions',
        'author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'submissions_categories',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category
            )
        )
    );

    $user_posts = get_posts( $args );

    if( count( $user_posts ) )
        return true;

}
```

By not working, I mean that `user_has_submitted_in_dog_category()` is not returning true. I call it in a template file as follows:

```
<?php if( $submission->user_has_submitted_in_dog_category() ) : ?>
    <div class="msg">You have already submitted.</div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="msg">You have not submitted yet.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The block of code prints `You have not submitted yet`, but I do have posts in my custom taxonomy `dog`.

Comment: How are you calling `user_has_submitted_in_dog_category()`

Comment: How do you define "not working"? Are you getting an error or something? What is the expected behavior versus what you're actually seeing? (hint: you probably want to put `return` in front of `$this->user_has_submitted_in_animal_category( 'dog' );` otherwise the return value won't get passed along when you call the outer function.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't work" means?  Error thrown?  Nothing happens?

Keep in mind that PHP's error output is turned off by default, so if you're getting no output, you may find it helpful to turn it on temporarily, or use a test environment where it's turned on.

Comment: Without having the complete class definition and instantiation code, it is hard to properly assess the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from your first (dog) method.

```
public function user_has_submitted_in_dog_category() {

    return $this->user_has_submitted_in_animal_category( 'dog' );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress might be calling the method statically. You might be best off doing that yourself as the method doesn't seem to need an object instance to work:

```
public function user_has_submitted_in_dog_category() {

  MyClass::user_has_submitted_in_animal_category( 'dog' );

}
```